# Firebase showing error TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have an error from firebase: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NINpQ.png)

Here is a snippet where the error probably occurs :

```
    const submit = async () => {
        if (name == "" || lastname == "" || email == "" || password == "") {
            alert("Please Enter All Value")

        } else {
            let dbref = ref(db, "user")
            get(dbref)
                .then((snapshot) => {
                    console.log(snapshot.val())
                    let data = Object.values(snapshot.val())
                    console.log(data)
                    let check = false
                    data.map((v, i) => {
                        if (v.email == email) {
                            check = true
                        }

                    });
```

If Anyone can help me ?

Thanks !

I'm trying to check if the user is already registered with the same email so I will alert already registered & if not so the form will proceed to next step.